# How to render CSS and HTML elements back to the Client's Browser from Form-POST acction and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am developing a web site that will allow users to make payments among peers and, I am trying to implement an easy mechanism through JavaScript and HTML Forms, simulating same approach that Stripe provides to embed Checkout buttons. (please see below Stripe sample code for Checkout button).

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_czwzkTp2tactuLOEOqbMTRzG"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

My question for this approach is the following:

1. What is the logic implemented in order to render a nice button that embed CSS and HTML elements back to the Client's browser.
2. Once the user click over the button, what is the logic to pass the
   Custom elements like Price Service, Service Description, etc, to the
   same Javascript that was in charge also of the CSS and HTML
   rendering from the question #1? Are we talking about one single
   Javascript file that handles all-in-one? or there is something else
   behind the hood?

Thanks in advance for this post, I just want a professional point of view regarding what i am trying to replicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing anything about Stripe, I can guess that when their script loads, they query the DOM for a script element that has the class *stripe-button*.

Then, they probably add their button element as a sibling of that script element and add all necessary handlers.

Here's a simple example:

*checkout.js*

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $script = $('script.stripe-button'), //find script el
        //create button
        $button = $('<button type="submit">').addClass('stripe-button').text($script.data('text'));


    $script
      //insert button after the script element
      .after($button)
      //listen to the submit event of the form
      .closest('form').submit(function (e) {
          console.log('performing checkout');
      });
});
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <script src="checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-text="Checkout"></script>
</form>
```

Comment: Your sample make sense, but I have one question: How to pass parameters like Price, Description, etc through the JavasScript? Do I missing something here?

Comment: @ChaleCS You want to pass these parameters to what? The button's plugin? The checkout service?

Comment: If you see the sample code from Stripe they are using the data-* attribute to pass parameters provided by the web developer. I would like to replicate same approach of passing parameters.

Comment: @ChaleCS Well that's part of my example already. If you noticed I added a `data-text` attribute to specify the button's text in my example. You can use the same approach for any other custom attributes.

Comment: Thanks plalx, you nailed it :-)